# Razor if / else inside a for loop: The for block is missing a closing "}" character

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am doing a simple for loop in Razor syntax in MVC:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProductViewModels.Count; i++)
{
    if (i%2 == 0)
    {
        <div class="row">
    }
        <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="/product?id=@Model.ProductViewModels[i].Id">@Model.ProductViewModels[i].Title - @Model.ProductViewModels[i].Isbn13
                <br />
                <img src="@Model.ProductViewModels[i].ImageUrl" />
            </a>
</div>

@if (i%2 == 0)
    {
        </div>
    }
}
```

This seems like pretty legal code in my mine mind, but it isn't working!

I get the error:

```
Meddelelse om parserfejl: The for block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.
```

Screenshot of error:

[image]

Any ideas? :) Thanks

Comment: For a (better) solution using helper class see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385181/razor-syntax-how-to-conditionally-wrap-some-inner-html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a working solution, I tested in Visual Studio on a Razor View. You have to use **@:** properly.

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProductViewModels.Count; i++)
  {            
       if (i % 2 == 0)
       {
           @:<div class="row">
       }

       <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="/product?id=@Model.ProductViewModels[i].Id">@Model.ProductViewModels[i].Title - @Model.ProductViewModels[i].Isbn13
          <br />
          <img src="@Model.ProductViewModels[i].ImageUrl" />
          </a>
       </div>

       if (i % 2 == 0)
       {
            @:</div>
       }            
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to use text tags

```
if (i%2 == 0)
{
    <text>
        <div class="row">
    </text>
}
```

here is a link with more information http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This solution work for me:

`

```
@foreach (var item in Model.listItems)
{
     if (item.isValid){
            @:<div class="validClass">
     }else{
            @:<div class="invalidClass">
     }
     @:</div>
}
```

`

You can try other solution as:

`<div class="@if(item.isValid){WriteLiteral("validClass");}" ></div>`

Comment: Explain why this solution is valid, don't just paste the code right here, is important to bring your expertise to the answer, helping the others to solve similar problems.

Comment: The first solution is functional but the second solutions is optimal

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
if (i%2 == 0)
{
    @:<div class="row">
}
```

Or:

```
if (i%2 == 0)
{
    <text>
        <div class="row">
    </text>
}
```

Read this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a "}" in the line above (line 8, before starting the code you pasted). the code you have pasted here doesnt have any problem.